# Можно ли установить Rust без VisualStudio 2022?

Tags: установка, rust

Я начинаю изучать Rust. Когда скачал установщик, увидел: чтобы установить Rust необходимо установить VisualStudio 2022. Могу ли я установить только язык, без IDE от Microsoft? VisualStudio занимает значительное место на моём ПК.

Comment: Вы можете выбрать, какой набор компонентов (toolchain) использовать: MSVC или GCC/MinGW (это можно сделать как при установке, так и после). Подробнее см. [The rustup book](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/installation/windows.html) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47380501).

Comment: Я не стал связываться с бинарником для Windows и поставил в WSL/Ubuntu. С VS Code работает превосходно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можно, но вы не сможете скомпилировать сторонние библиотеки, для которых нужен компилятор C/C++

для установки Rust воспользуйтесь инструкцией с сайта https://www.rust-lang.org/ru/tools/install

в качестве IDE рекомендую JetBrains Community edition с плагином для Rust

Comment: Azmandios, спасибо!

Comment: Сторонние библиотеки можно и в [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) собирать, на VisualStudio свет клином не сошёлся.

Comment: @zed, мне при установке Rust предлагается только установка вместе в VisualStudio и msys2. Поэтому и задал вопрос :)